# Progress bar with Apache FileUtils.copyDirectory(...)

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-io, fileutils

Does anyone know any way of implementing progress bar for Apache's `FileUtils.copyDirectory(File src, File dst)`? I don't see anything helpful in [JavaDocs](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) and API. Seems like a common use case in dealing with batch disk operations, so I'm not sure if I miss something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you will have to do that yourself. I see this immediate solution:

1. Find all files you are about to copy and count the number or total file size first (depending on what your progress bar should measure)
2. Copy the files using [`FileUtils.copyDirectory(File, File, FileFilter)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20java.io.FileFilter%29) and "abuse" the `FileFilter` as a callback to communicate progress to your progress bar

Comment: Yes, I guess `FileFilter` can do the trick. Nasty, but working and better then rewriting whole method, so I'll accept it anytime :)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested, I did this by coping the `doCopyFile` method from FileUtils and the couple of methods that lead up to it. I then pasted them into a new class so that I could edit the methods rather than only using the fixed FileUtils methods.

Then I changed this part of the `doCopyFile` method:

```
pos += output.transferFrom(input, pos, count);
```

To this: (update the progress bar every time the buffer is emptied, not the best way)

```
//Split into into deceleration and assignment to count bytes transfered
long bytesTransfered = output.transferFrom(input, pos, count);
//complete original method
pos += bytesTransfered;
//update total bytes copied, so it can be used to calculate progress
bytesTransferedTotal += bytesTransfered;
//your code to update progress bar here
ProgressBar.setValue((int) Math.floor((100.0 / totalSize) * bytesTransferedTotal));
```

---

For a better way the copy would be run in a different thread, and the progress bar would be updated in the EDT (using the `bytesTransfered` value and the total size of the files that are being copied):

```
long bytesTransfered = output.transferFrom(input, pos, count);
pos += bytesTransfered;
bytesTransferedTotal += bytesTransfered;
```

Then to update the progress bar on the EDT fire events with something like this:

```
ProgressBar.setValue((int) Math.floor((100.0 / totalSizeOfFiles) * bytesTransferedTotal));
```