# How to call the OS functionality to copy over files to a folder?

Tags: java, operating-system, copy

I a Java app, I need to synchronize the contents of two user-selected directories, Source and Target(simple local machine app, no need to consider any filesystem or server stuff and whatnot). The app should copy any new and changed files from Source to the Target and delete any files that are not in the Source but are in the Target. The synchronization process needs to display a progress bar and be cancelable.

The deleting part I guess I'll have to write entirely, but the other behavior is the same as the OS functionality to copy over files from one directory to another, so I could save myself a lot of work by using the functionality that is already there. The problem is, I have no idea how to access it from Java.

So, how do I make Java do the same thing that happens on most OSs if you select some files and drag them onto a folder icon?

Comment: You can run `rsync` which will work even between two machines using Runtime.exec()

Comment: To get the OS to do this, you need to find the appropriate command line tool to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java's [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to watch a directory for changes. Since you are using two directories, you would need to watch both the directories for changes.

For progress bars and drag and drop, you would need either [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) or Swing.

Trying to communicate with native OS calls would be - difficult and if possible, platform dependent. Moreover, you would need to know if the OS actually exposes these sort of features to a non OS code.

Answer (score 1):

Apache fileutils does have quite a few handy methods dealing with copying files. Check this thread [Progress bar with Apache FileUtils.copyDirectory(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427303/progress-bar-with-apache-fileutils-copydirectory) for some inspiration

/Bjorn